# Do the Drowned carry enchanted tridents?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Since the only way to get a trident is from a drowned, I was wondering if a drowned could be holding an enchanted trident. (Why you ask? Because I’m short on levels and I’m too lazy to make a mob farm - I don’t want to have to enchant it myself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The short answer: No

### The long answer:

Drowned can only spawn with enchanted tridents on Minecraft: Java Edition.

> In **Java Edition**, a trident held by a drowned has a chance to be enchanted, but the trident's enchantments have no effects for drowned.

From the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trident)